# Nexenta After the Death of OpenSolaris

Tags: zfs, opensolaris, nexenta, illumos

We are thinking of evaluating Nexenta for a Tier 2 storage solution.  It looks great, but I have doubts over its future after the demise of OpenSolaris.

I know that Nexenta uses an OpenSolaris kernel and ZFS.  Now that OpenSolaris is no more, will Nexenta die a slow and painful death?

I have scoured the net, and there does not seem to be any discussion on this topic out there.  Anyone in the server fault community know if Nexenta has a future with OpenSolaris dead?

Also, anyone have any "in production" Nexenta experiences to share?

Answer (score 3):

Nexenta, Joyent, and a handful of others seem to have gotten behind [Illumos](http://www.illumos.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Nexenta is indeed utilizing Illumos as the OS core. From what I understand, the OpenSolaris and ZFS bits they are using are truely open-sourced, and that genie can't be put back in the Sun/Oracle bottle. See [this page](http://blogs.nexenta.org/blog/2010/07/06/coraid-zfs-netapp-and-nexenta/) for Nexenta's statement on this.

We are currently building out a 16TB Nexenta Enterprise box... I'll let you know how it goes. Pre-sales support experience was OK however (I had questions on zfs send/recv usage and NIS support.)

Comment: I would also like to hear about it.

Comment: So far, I like the product, but I've honestly had a poor support experience (system would not boot due to a misconfigured hostname.<nic> file that was not updated at initial config thru NMV, spent DAYS working with Nexenta support, all they did was send me links from Google to *try* to solve the problem, which we finally solved ourselves...)

Answer (score 1):

I have deployed a series of boxes with Nexenta (about 250TB total deployment atm.) There was a learning curve for our Linux only shop, but all in Nexenta is a solid product and ZFS is a fantastic filesystem. I don't regret making the move at all.

Oracle has not totally killed OpenSolaris, what they have said is that instead of doing development in public, once they do a full release of Solaris 11, they will do a code dump for all the OpenSolaris community to merge in. So Nexenta will still get updates from the Oracle Devs, you will just need to wait longer.